# What is the connection between Jesus’s sanctification and His disciples’ sanctification in John 17:19?

Tags: john, jesus, disciple, sanctification

John 17:19 (NASB)

> For their sakes I sanctify Myself, that they themselves also may be sanctified in truth.

What is the connection between Jesus’s sanctification and His disciples’ sanctification? How would Him sanctifying Himself allow for their sanctification?

Answer (score 2):

Jesus was already pure, holy, and undefiled.  He was sinless, and therefore we could say he had been "sanctified" already.  But as we observe his life, we see that he *exemplified*, through his own behavior, the sanctification that his disciples needed.  This was to show them how they might also be sanctified.

For example, in Jesus' baptism, he exemplified what he asked of his disciples, to help them understand their need of cleansing from sin.

John knew Jesus did not need to be baptized, and at first objected to it.

> But John forbad him, saying, I have need to be baptized of thee, and
> comest thou to me? And Jesus answering said unto him, Suffer it to be
> so now: for thus it becometh us to fulfil all righteousness. Then he
> suffered him. (Matthew 3:14-15, KJV)

We see that Jesus did this as an example to his disciples in order "to fulfil all righteousness."  This is a prime example of how Jesus would sanctify himself for the sake of his disciples.

Jesus also fasted and prayed, spending almost entire nights in prayer to the Father, thus obtaining strength for himself and providing his disciples practical lessons in sanctification.

> And in the morning, rising up a great while before day, he went out,
> and departed into a solitary place, and there prayed. (Mark 1:35, KJV)

Jesus gives us the reason for these things in the text of the question.

> And for their sakes I sanctify myself, that they also might be
> sanctified through the truth. (John 17:19, KJV)

**Conclusion**

Jesus' entire mission to earth was one of *communication* and of *education.*  It was God's plan to teach us, by living example--in a way that all could easily see and understand, how we might be sanctified and restored to communion with heaven.  Every one of his words and acts came with this object in view.

Jesus' example, his sanctifying example, was for the benefit of all those who should afterward follow in the path of sanctification.

Answer (score 1):

English Standard Version, John 17:19a

> And for their sake I consecrate myself

This is a euphemism: Jesus consecrated/sanctified himself by going to the Cross. It alludes to the consecration in Exodus 13:

> 2 “**Consecrate** to me every firstborn male. The first offspring of every womb among the Israelites belongs to me, whether human or animal.”

After the Cross, 19b:

> that they also may be sanctified in truth.

Now, the believers may be sanctified in the truth of the Cross, Hebrews 10:

> 10
> And by that will, we have been **sanctified** through the **sacrifice** of the body of Jesus Christ once for all.

What is the connection between Jesus’s sanctification and His disciples’ sanctification in John 17:19?

Jesus’s sanctification was the act of the Cross. Through it, we are sanctified by his blood.